# Inserting ole object to TRxRichEdit

Tags: delphi, richtext

I'm using TRxRichEdit in my program. How can I insert ole object to RxRichEdit at run time.

Answer (score 1):

If you call "InsertObjectDialog" method of the RxRichEdit, the control executes the Insert Object dialog where the user can choose the type of the object to create anew or from an existing file.

<strike>I don't think it would be possible to insert an object without using the dialog, because the IRichEditOle interface (FRichEditOle) is private to the class.</strike>

**edit:**

Regardless the interface being private or not to the class, apparently, one can request the [`IRichEditOle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface directly from the RichEdit control itself by using [`EM_GETOLEINTERFACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Below is D3 sample code (the last version I used RX controls with), but it would also probably suit the 'TJvRichEdit' of JVCL, which is originally the same control. The code inserts an Ole object from a file name at run-time:

```
uses
  activex, richedit, comobj;

type
  _ReObject = record
    cbStruct: DWORD;
    cp: ULONG;
    clsid: TCLSID;
    poleobj: IOleObject;
    pstg: IStorage;
    polesite: IOleClientSite;
    sizel: TSize;
    dvAspect: Longint;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
    dwUser: DWORD;
  end;
  TReObject = _ReObject;

  IRichEditOle = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{00020d00-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}']
    function GetClientSite(out clientSite: IOleClientSite): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetObjectCount: HResult; stdcall;
    function GetLinkCount: HResult; stdcall;
    function GetObject(iob: Longint; out reobject: TReObject;
        dwFlags: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function InsertObject(var reobject: TReObject): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertObject(iob: Longint; rclsidNew: TIID;
        lpstrUserTypeNew: LPCSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function ActivateAs(rclsid: TIID; rclsidAs: TIID): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetHostNames(lpstrContainerApp: LPCSTR;
        lpstrContainerObj: LPCSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetLinkAvailable(iob: Longint; fAvailable: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetDvaspect(iob: Longint; dvaspect: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function HandsOffStorage(iob: Longint): HResult; stdcall;
    function SaveCompleted(iob: Longint; const stg: IStorage): HResult; stdcall;
    function InPlaceDeactivate: HResult; stdcall;
    function ContextSensitiveHelp(fEnterMode: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetClipboardData(var chrg: TCharRange; reco: DWORD;
        out dataobj: IDataObject): HResult; stdcall;
    function ImportDataObject(dataobj: IDataObject; cf: TClipFormat;
        hMetaPict: HGLOBAL): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

const
  REO_CP_SELECTION    = ULONG(-1);
  REO_RESIZABLE       = $00000001;
  IID_IOleObject: TGUID = (
      D1:$00000112;D2:$0000;D3:$0000;D4:($C0,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$46));

procedure InsertOleObjectFromFile(RichEdit: TRxRichEdit; FileName: string);
var
  RichEditOle: IRichEditOle;
  LockBytes: ILockBytes;
  Storage: IStorage;
  FormatEtc: TFormatEtc;
  ClientSite: IOleClientSite;
  OleObject: IOleObject;
  ClassID: TCLSID;
  ReObject: TReObject;
begin
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, Longint(@RichEditOle));
  if not Assigned(RichEditOle) then
    raise EOleError.Create('Failed to retrieve IRichEditOle');
  OleCheck(CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(0, True, LockBytes));
  OleCheck(StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes(LockBytes,
      STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE or STGM_CREATE or STGM_READWRITE, 0, Storage));
  LockBytes := nil;

  OleCheck(RichEditOle.GetClientSite(ClientSite));
  FillChar(FormatEtc, SizeOf(FormatEtc), 0);
  FormatEtc.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
  FormatEtc.lIndex := -1;
  OleCheck(OleCreateFromFile(GUID_NULL, PWideChar(WideString(FileName)),
      IID_IOleObject, OLERENDER_DRAW, @FormatEtc, ClientSite, Storage,
      OleObject));
  OleCheck(OleSetContainedObject(OleObject, True));

  OleCheck(OleObject.GetUserClassID(ClassID));
  FillChar(ReObject, SizeOf(TReObject), 0);
  ReObject.cbStruct := SizeOf(TReObject);
  ReObject.cp := REO_CP_SELECTION;
  ReObject.clsid := ClassID;
  ReObject.poleobj := OleObject;
  ReObject.pstg := Storage;
  ReObject.polesite := ClientSite;
  ReObject.dvAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
  ReObject.dwFlags := REO_RESIZABLE;
  OleCheck(RichEditOle.InsertObject(ReObject));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InsertOleObjectFromFile(RxRichEdit1,
      ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'xltest.xls');
end;
```